# Как изменить цвет фона на белый при использовании функции imagerotate?

Tags: gd, php

В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagerotate.php) описана эта функция:

```
resource imagerotate ( resource $image , float $angle , int $bgd_color [, int ignore_transparent = 0 ] )
```

> bgd_color Цвет фона свободной зоны после поворота.

А как перевести белый цвет в int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xffffff` - белый

для других цветов можно воспользоваться функцией:

```
function createcolor($r, $g, $b) {
  return hexdec(str_pad(dechex($r), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($g), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($b), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT));
}
```

$r,$g,$b соответвенно красный, зеленый, синий от 0 до 255